# How to setup Geb running with firefox and TestNg?

Tags: firefox, testng, geb

I tried to setup Geb to start and writing my automation code, but I found it difficult and did manage to do so despite Geb wiki (http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/).

I didn't find any sufficient example.

Please, does anyone have any setup example that works with Firefox and TestNg?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Geb example project [here](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle). It contains examples for JUnit and Spock and you can run tests using Firefox, Chrome and PhantomJS. It doesn't contain examples for TestNG, but adding one would be as easy as adding a dependency on [`geb-testng` module](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.gebish%22%20AND%20a%3A%22geb-testng%22) and converting the JUnit class to a TestNG one.

Comment: And that project is [mentioned in the docs](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/testing.html#example_projects)